# When i try to use method it give error

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, switch-statement, goto

i have a `switch` statement in which i try to check for `string` values, i want that after checking for name it should ask for marks. But when i try to make an `if else` statement in a method it gives error.

here is the code which runs fine :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class java {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        final int pass = 33;
        String Student;
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        Student = obj.nextLine();
        switch (Student) {
            case "Ram":
                System.out.println("Students name is " + Student);
                break;
            case "Shyaam":
                System.out.println("Students name is " + Student);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("This name is not recognised");

        }

        System.out.println("Enter your marks");
        num = obj.nextInt();
        if (num < pass) {
            System.out.println(Student + " You have failed the subject");
        } else {
            System.out.println(Student + " You have passed the subject");
        }
    }
}
```

but in this even if name does not get verified it still ask for marks.

what should i do.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `switch` statement is not a `while switch` statement.

To allow to take another input, include the `switch` in a `while` that goes on while the student String is not valid.
Besides, you should respect conventions : the variable name should start with a lowercase.
`String student` is correct. `String Student` is not.

```
 String student = null;

 while (student == null){
    student = obj.nextLine();

    switch(student){
      case "Ram":
        System.out.println("Students name is "+ Student);
        break;
      case "Shyaam":
        System.out.println("Students name is "+ Student);
        break;
      default:
          System.out.println("This name is not recognised");
          student = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this and what should i do to ask for marks after getting the name, i mean i want that if name is incorrect then it should not ask for marks from user.

Comment: The while statement is designed to solve this issue. In the presented code, while the input for the name is invalid, the executed code loops in the while. When the executed code happens to be after the while statement, it means that the name is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You should close class.
Add "}" to the end of class

Comment: i didn't added that ..sorry ..but it is there in the code. But my question is different

Answer (score 0):

You can move `if` condition to, inside of the `switch`.

```
switch(Student){
       case "Ram":
       System.out.println("Students name is "+ Student);

       System.out.println("Enter your marks");
       num=obj.nextInt();

       if(num<pass){   
           System.out.println(Student+" You have failed the subject");
       }else{
           System.out.println(Student+" You have passed the subject");
           }

           break;
       case "Shyaam":
       System.out.println("Students name is "+ Student);

       System.out.println("Enter your marks");
       num=obj.nextInt();

       if(num<pass){   
           System.out.println(Student+" You have failed the subject");
       }else{
           System.out.println(Student+" You have passed the subject");
       }
       break;
       default:
           System.out.println("This name is not recognised");
    }
```

But this will lead you to more codes to avoid that you can use one more variable to check if student name match. To do that you have to use `boolean` variable.

Then code should be:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
   int num;
   final int pass=33;

   String Student;
   System.out.println("Please enter your name");
   Student=obj.nextLine();

   boolean isStudent = false;

   switch(Student){
     case "Ram":
         isStudent = true;
       System.out.println("Students name is "+ Student);
       break;
     case "Shyaam":
         isStudent = true;
       System.out.println("Students name is "+ Student);
       break;
     default:
       System.out.println("This name is not recognised");
   } 

   if(isStudent){
       System.out.println("Enter your marks");
       num=obj.nextInt();

       if(num<pass){   
           System.out.println(Student+" You have failed the subject");
       }else{
           System.out.println(Student+" You have passed the subject");
       }
   }else{
       System.out.println("You are not a ....");
   }
}
```

Note: this is a one way to do this.

Comment: yeah , i tried this one and it worked but the problem with this is i have to right it for like many times and comparing with every name is very difficult. BTW thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @RishavSharma please refer the answer again I updated it to match your requirement.